# Javascript Regex Extract Url and Dimension in SrcSet Attribute String

Tags: javascript, regex

This objective in this question is to extract a URL and dimension from a `srcset` html attribute string. Specifically the parameters here are the following:

- Url starts with `http` or `https`
- Url may contain `,`
- Url *cannot* contain spaces
- Dimension contains digits followed by `x` or `w`. Potentially doesn't even need to be followed by either of those though.

Because of this, the desired method for matching is to find the http/https and match until a space, then match digits immediately followed by a `w` or `x`, then a comma. A space following this would denote the end of the match.

This usually looks like `https://url.com 650w` or `https://url.com 650` or `https://url.com 650x`. There is no strict standard here.

Here is my attempted regex with the [Regex101 demo here](https://regex101.com/r/69F1zL/4). The problem here is that it's not grouping correctly:

`(https?:\/\/(?:.*(?:\s+\d+[wx])(?:,\s*)?)+)`

Sample string to parse:

```
http://media.endclothing.com/media/f_auto,w_600,h_600/prodmedia/media/catalog/product/0/4/04-12-2021_LL_212ATDT-CP02S-OD_1_1.jpg 640w, http://media.endclothing.com/media/f_auto,w_600,h_600/prodmedia/media/catalog/product/0/4/04-12-2021_LL_212ATDT-CP02S-OD_1_1.jpg 750w, https://media.endclothing.com/media/f_auto,w_600,h_600/prodmedia/media/catalog/product/0/4/04-12-2021_LL_212ATDT-CP02S-OD_1_1.jpg 828, https://media.endclothing.com/media/f_auto,w_600,h_600/prodmedia/media/catalog/product/0/4/04-12-2021_LL_212ATDT-CP02S-OD_1_1.jpg 1080x, https://media.endclothing.com/media/f_auto,w_600,h_600/prodmedia/media/catalog/product/0/4/04-12-2021_LL_212ATDT-CP02S-OD_1_1.jpg 1200w, https://media.endclothing.com/media/f_auto,w_600,h_600/prodmedia/media/catalog/product/0/4/04-12-2021_LL_212ATDT-CP02S-OD_1_1.jpg 1920w, https://media.endclothing.com/media/f_auto,w_600,h_600/prodmedia/media/catalog/product/0/4/04-12-2021_LL_212ATDT-CP02S-OD_1_1.jpg 2048w, https://media.endclothing.com/media/f_auto,w_600,h_600/prodmedia/media/catalog/product/0/4/04-12-2021_LL_212ATDT-CP02S-OD_1_1.jpg 3840w,https://media.endclothing.com/media/f_auto,w_600,h_600/prodmedia/media/catalog/product/0/4/04-12-2021_LL_212ATDT-CP02S-OD_1_1.jpg 3840w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599420186946-7b6fb4e297f0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=100&q=60 100w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599420186946-7b6fb4e297f0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=200&q=60 200w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599420186946-7b6fb4e297f0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=300&q=60 300w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599420186946-7b6fb4e297f0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&q=60 400w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599420186946-7b6fb4e297f0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60 500w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599420186946-7b6fb4e297f0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60 600w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599420186946-7b6fb4e297f0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60 700w
```

The outcome of this should be:

```
http://media.endclothing.com/media/f_auto,w_600,h_600/prodmedia/media/catalog/product/0/4/04-12-2021_LL_212ATDT-CP02S-OD_1_1.jpg 640w
http://media.endclothing.com/media/f_auto,w_600,h_600/prodmedia/media/catalog/product/0/4/04-12-2021_LL_212ATDT-CP02S-OD_1_1.jpg 750w
https://media.endclothing.com/media/f_auto,w_600,h_600/prodmedia/media/catalog/product/0/4/04-12-2021_LL_212ATDT-CP02S-OD_1_1.jpg 828
https://media.endclothing.com/media/f_auto,w_600,h_600/prodmedia/media/catalog/product/0/4/04-12-2021_LL_212ATDT-CP02S-OD_1_1.jpg 1080x
https://media.endclothing.com/media/f_auto,w_600,h_600/prodmedia/media/catalog/product/0/4/04-12-2021_LL_212ATDT-CP02S-OD_1_1.jpg 1200w
https://media.endclothing.com/media/f_auto,w_600,h_600/prodmedia/media/catalog/product/0/4/04-12-2021_LL_212ATDT-CP02S-OD_1_1.jpg 1920w
https://media.endclothing.com/media/f_auto,w_600,h_600/prodmedia/media/catalog/product/0/4/04-12-2021_LL_212ATDT-CP02S-OD_1_1.jpg 2048w
https://media.endclothing.com/media/f_auto,w_600,h_600/prodmedia/media/catalog/product/0/4/04-12-2021_LL_212ATDT-CP02S-OD_1_1.jpg 3840w
https://media.endclothing.com/media/f_auto,w_600,h_600/prodmedia/media/catalog/product/0/4/04-12-2021_LL_212ATDT-CP02S-OD_1_1.jpg 3840w
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599420186946-7b6fb4e297f0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=100&q=60 100w
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599420186946-7b6fb4e297f0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=200&q=60 200w
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599420186946-7b6fb4e297f0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=300&q=60 300w
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599420186946-7b6fb4e297f0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&q=60 400w
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599420186946-7b6fb4e297f0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60 500w
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599420186946-7b6fb4e297f0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60 600w
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599420186946-7b6fb4e297f0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60 700w
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 4 points in the question, and to get the outcome of the example string, you can use:

```
https?:\/\/\S* \d+[xw]?(?=,|$)
```

The pattern matches:

- `https?:\/\/` Match the protocol for http and https
- `\S*`  Match optional non whitespace chars (can contain a comma) and then a space
- `\d+[xw]?` Match 1+ digits and optional `x` or `w`
- `(?=,|$)` Positive lookahead, assert either a `,` or the end of the string to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KlHRyQ/1)